# how to use .swc file in flex project

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, swc

I have a flex project in which I need to `as3xls library (.swc file)` in my project. Now I have downloaded that swc file and included it in f`lex-sdk\frameworks\libs` and I am able to use the .as files of that swc file.

Now If I have tried to put the swc file in my local project, for e.g. in one of my package of components and added it to the class path (using `eclipse project properties -> flex build path`) and tried to use it from that location but I am unable to compile the project as its not able to import the .as files.

Can anybody suggest the location where I should add the `.swc` file and use it in my project ?

Comment: copy these .swc file to the 'lib' folder in your project folder

Comment: you mean to say flex-project -> lib folder ?

Comment: libs Folder of your flex project...

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Flash Builder, I generally create a *libs* folder under the project:

> [image: folder-hierarchy]

Then, reference the SWC by selecting the project *Properties*, *ActionScript Build Path* where you can either add an individual SWC or SWC Folder:

> [image: properties]

Comment: I have added swc file to flex-project->libs then using eclipse -> project properties added it to the library path... still its not able to compile.

Answer (score 2):

Check out my blog post on [How to use a SWC](https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/12/18/What-do-you-do-with-a-SWC?event=PurchaseHistory).

Here is the important points:

> There are three different ways that you can use the classes that
>   reside in a SWC file:
>   * **Library Path in Project Properties**: This is how
>   I use SWCs most commonly.
>   * **Libs folder**: The libs folder was introduced
>   in Flex Builder 3. If you put a SWC into a libs folder it is
>   automatically added to your library path, and all the classes in the
>   SWC are available from your project
>   * **Library Path command line
>   argument**: You can use the [library path argument](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/compilers_19.html#158337) to the mxmlc command
>   line compiler.

Comment: I have tried with the first approach u have suggest of "Library Path in Project Properties". With that its actually showing as a valid import (by pressing ctrl+space), but when I am building my flex project its showing error of "unknown type".

Comment: Try cleaning the project.  If that doesn't help; then you'll have to share some code to demo the problem.

Comment: I am using as3xls library for exporting to excel, for that I have one .swc file. And that swc file contains few .as files, which I am able to import it in my project (by ctrl+space) but while building the project its throwing an error.